# remove duplicates from arraylist

Tags: c, arraylist, duplicates

I'm trying to remove duplicates from an ArrayList. Every element is repeated not more than 5 times. Why is it always leaving 2 of each duplicate? (0,0,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5).

```
void quitarRepetidos_lista(ArrayList* lista)
{
    eNumero* auxNumero;
    eNumero* auxNumero2;
    int i,j;

    if ( lista != NULL  )
    {
        for (i = 0; i<lista->len(lista); i++)
        {
            auxNumero = lista->get(lista,i);
            for ( j = i+1; j<lista->len(lista); j++ )
            {
                auxNumero2 = lista->get(lista,j);
                if ( numero_compare(auxNumero,auxNumero2) == 0)
                {
                    lista->remove(lista,j);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
int numero_compare(eNumero* numeroAlfa, eNumero* numeroBeta)
{
    if ( ((eNumero*)numeroAlfa)->numero >((eNumero*)numeroBeta)->numero )
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if ( ((eNumero*)numeroAlfa)->numero < ((eNumero*)numeroBeta)->numero )
    {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

it should say 012345[image]

Comment: What's an ArrayList? Never heard of it. Consult the documentation for the third-part library you're using.

Comment: @GMP_47  This condition  i<lista->len(lista) already does not make sense. Why not just  i<lista->len()?

Comment: Where is `ArrayList` defined?

Comment: @GMP_47 It seems the problem in the loops. For example if in this loop  for ( j = i+1; j<lista->len(lista); j++ ) an item was deleted then j shall not be increased.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the fact that your code is not correct in C (you are calling methods on pointers, eg `lista->remove(...)` but C doesn't have objects).

This is just a guess since we can't know the implementation or the interface of `ArrayList` class (which curiously mimics the name of the one from Java SDK) but when you do

```
lista->remove(lista,j);
```

usually this makes all elements after the one at `j` shift back by one position (since you are removing **j-th** then **(j+1)-th** becomes **j-th**, filling the hole).

```
          j
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| A | B | C | D | E | F |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+

erase element at j

          j
+---+---+---+---+---+
| A | B | D | E | F |
+---+---+---+---+---+

for loop body ends, j is incremented

              j
+---+---+---+---+---+
| A | B | D | E | F |
+---+---+---+---+---+

D has been skipped
```

But since you are inside a loop, `j` is then incremented by the for afterthought, effectively skipping one element. You should do something like:

```
for ( j = i+1; j < lista->len(); /* no after thought */) {
  if (are equal)
    lista->remove(j);
  else
    ++j;
```

So that you don't increment `j` if you just removed an element, since the next element will be placed still at `j`.

Comment: It crashes. 
Forgot to say that al_remove() has a contract() function that rezises down the arraylist
EDIT: seems like it iterates 5 times before crashing.

Comment: This shouldn't be relevant as long as you are not caching the size of the list since at each loop iteration `j` is checked against again `lista->len()` (which will be lesser)

Answer (score 1):

After removing an element from your list, you shouldn't increment `j`, otherwise you'd end up skipping the very next element (which takes on the index of the element that was just removed).

Instead of:

```
if ( numero_compare(auxNumero,auxNumero2) == 0)
{
    lista->remove(lista,j);
}
```

You should decrement `j` only when an element is removed:

```
if ( numero_compare(auxNumero,auxNumero2) == 0)
{
    lista->remove(lista,j--);
}
```

Comment: It crashes with that.

Comment: @GMP_47 Show us your code for `len()`, `get()`, and `remove()`

Comment: https://github.com/aflorio91/Modelo_P1_Laboratorio_1/tree/master/1F_SP_FlorioAndres here you'll find all the arraylist funcions in ArrayList.c.

Answer (score 1):

> It crashes…

In addition to the error treated by Jack and frslm, there are errors in [`ArrayList.c`, function `resizeDown()`](https://github.com/aflorio91/Modelo_P1_Laboratorio_1/blob/master/1F_SP_FlorioAndres/ArrayList.c#L486).

1. `newLen = (pList->reservedSize - pList->size);`
   Since the reserved size of the list is to be shrinked when there are more than `AL_INCREMENT` unused elements (see [`contract()`](https://github.com/aflorio91/Modelo_P1_Laboratorio_1/blob/master/1F_SP_FlorioAndres/ArrayList.c#L539)), `reservedSize` has to be reduced by `AL_INCREMENT` rather than by `pList->size`, which latter lead to a way to small `newLen`. Correct:
   `newLen = pList->reservedSize - AL_INCREMENT;`
2. `pList->size = newLen;`
   Since function `resizeDown()` is only to shrink the allocated space for the list, not remove an element from it (what `contract()` already did), `newLen` has to be assigned to `reservedSize` rather than to `pList->size`. Correct:
   `pList->reservedSize = newLen;`